# Two Additional types in default constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Since I've been using **kotlin-reflect** to invoke my default and declared one, I see second different constructor.

I have realized that two different fields **int arg3** and **kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker arg4** added to my constructor.

```
data class Model(
    @SerializedName("xyz") val entity: String?,
    @SerializedName("abc") val id: Long? = null
)
val constructors = clazz.declaredConstructors // how I call the constructors
```

My actual question is why I have these 2 fields and what is the logic behind it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These two parameters are added to special synthetic members generated by the Kotlin compiler for all functions and constructors with default parameters.

With Java reflection, you can filter out these synthetic functions and constructors by checking [`isSynthetic()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#isSynthetic()) and finding the one that is not.

The integer parameter is a bit mask. When such a function is called from Kotlin, a bit mask is generated and passed as the argument. The bits show which of the default parameters of the function are passed explicit arguments and which should use the default value.

The `DefaultConstructorMarker` parameter is used to ensure there's no collision of the synthetic constructor (accepting the bit mask) with a different constructor which has a signature with those same arguments and an `Int` in the end. The argument passed to the marker parameter is not used in any way, and it is always `null`.

In fact, there are two methods or constructors generated for each function or constructor, respectively, that has at least one default parameter: one with the same signature as declared and no additional parameters, and the other also accepting a bit mask and the marker.

If you inspect the bytecode of such a function, you will find roughly the following, for a function declaration:

```
fun foo(bar: String, baz: List<String> = emptyList(), qux: Set<String> = emptySet()) = 0
```

The real method in the bytecode is:

```
// access flags 0x19
// signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;Ljava/util/Set<Ljava/lang/String;>;)I
// declaration: int foo(java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)
public final static foo(
    Ljava/lang/String;
    Ljava/util/List;
    Ljava/util/Set;
)I
  // annotable parameter count: 3 (visible)
  // annotable parameter count: 3 (invisible)
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 1
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 2
L0
  ALOAD 0
  LDC "bar"
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  ALOAD 1
  LDC "baz"
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  ALOAD 2
  LDC "qux"
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
L1
  LINENUMBER 16 L1
  ICONST_0
  IRETURN
L2
  LOCALVARIABLE bar Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
  LOCALVARIABLE baz Ljava/util/List; L0 L2 1
  LOCALVARIABLE qux Ljava/util/Set; L0 L2 2
  MAXSTACK = 2
  MAXLOCALS = 3
```

And the generated wrapper that handles the bit mask and calculates the default values if necessary is a separate method:

```
// access flags 0x1009
public static synthetic foo$default(
    Ljava/lang/String;
    Ljava/util/List;
    Ljava/util/Set;
    I
    Ljava/lang/Object;
)I
  ILOAD 3
  ICONST_2
  IAND
  IFEQ L0
L1
  LINENUMBER 16 L1
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/collections/CollectionsKt.emptyList ()Ljava/util/List;
  ASTORE 1
L0
  ILOAD 3
  ICONST_4
  IAND
  IFEQ L2
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/collections/SetsKt.emptySet ()Ljava/util/Set;
  ASTORE 2
L2
  ALOAD 0
  ALOAD 1
  ALOAD 2
  INVOKESTATIC FooKt.foo (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Set;)I
  IRETURN
  MAXSTACK = 3
  MAXLOCALS = 5
```

Note how the latter checks the bit mask (with `ILOAD 3`, `ICONST_x`, `IAND`) and then conditionally (when `IFEQ Lx` doesn't skip it) evaluates the default arguments.

Constructors are different from ordinary functions in that they can't have a suffix `$default` in the name, so the marker is necessary to avoid possible signatures conflict.

Comment: UPD: added a way to find a real constructor rather than a synthetic one.